# How to set the dimensions of the initial pose array

Tags: ros, navigation, pose, array, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The initial pose array is really much bigger than it needs to be.  How do I change it's initial dimensions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9752/how-to-set-the-dimensions-of-the-initial-pose-array/) by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 995 on 2011-04-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on 2011-04-18**:
No I don't mean the number of particles, I mean the dimensions over which the particles are initially distributed.

**Comment by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) on 2011-04-18**:
That's a good point actually, I guess you can change the dimensions of that array by changing the number of particles AMCL uses.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-04-18**:
Do you mean the number of particles (elements in the array) or just the overall spread of those particles, say, when visualized in rviz?

**Comment by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on 2011-04-17**:
There is an array of poses published to /particlecloud, I think by amcl.

**Comment by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) on 2011-04-17**:
I'm not totally sure what array you're referring to. Are you talking about the PoseWithCovarianceStamped message that's sent to AMCL? The ParticleCloud message published by AMCL? Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From looking at the code, AMCL sizes the pose array in the "particlecloud" message to be the size of the number of guesses it currently has for the robot's pose. There's no way to change its initial dimensions. If you just want the current pose of the robot displayed in rviz, you can enable TF frames and look at the "base_link" frame relative to the "map" frame. The "particlecloud" message, provides a visualization that helps give insight into the particle filter AMCL uses internally.

---

Originally posted by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0